# How to transcribe full audio text from a .wav file?

Tags: node.js, azure, speech-to-text

It is not transcribing full audio file and the process is exciting before trancribing the full audio file. It is only transcribing first few seconds of the audio file.

I referred this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-js-node#prerequisites

Can somebody help me out with this?

```
// pull in the required packages.
var sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
var fs = require("fs");

var axios = require('axios')

// replace with your own subscription key,
// service region (e.g., "westus"), and
// the name of the file you want to run
// through the speech recognizer.
var subscriptionKey = "";
var serviceRegion = ""; // e.g., "westus"
var filename = "output2.wav"; // 16000 Hz, Mono

// create the push stream we need for the speech sdk.
var pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream();

// open the file and push it to the push stream.
fs.createReadStream(filename).on('data', function (arrayBuffer) {
    // console.log(arrayBuffer);
    pushStream.write(arrayBuffer.buffer);
}).on('end', function () {
    pushStream.close();
});

// we are done with the setup
console.log("Now recognizing from: " + filename);

// now create the audio-config pointing to our stream and
// the speech config specifying the language.
var audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(pushStream);
var speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, serviceRegion);

// setting the recognition language to English.
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

// create the speech recognizer.
var recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

// start the recognizer and wait for a result.
recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
    function (result) {
        console.log(result);

        recognizer.close();
        recognizer = undefined;
    },
    function (err) {
        console.trace("err - " + err);

        recognizer.close();
        recognizer = undefined;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [StartContinuousRecognitionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer.startcontinuousrecognitionasync?view=azure-dotnet) instead of recognizeOnceAsync

Comment: **Does this function provide some callback or result like recognizeOnceAsync? To Fetch speech text??**

Comment: recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync()

**//In between this how do i fetch data**

recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync()